# In Groovy, how to extract only matching strings from a list?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my groovy script, I have a list like below

```
subList = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

and a text file `master_list.txt` with below content:

```
MASTER_STRING="ping:123 foo:321 pong:999 bar:888"
OTHER_STRING=helloWorld
```

I need to get the only the matching items form `MASTER_STRING`, so from above example, I need to get a list like
`["foo:321", "bar:888"]`

I am very new to groovy, I could find if a matching sub string found in `MASTER_LIST` which is there in `subList`, but how to extract the required strings as list?

```
props = readProperties file: "master_list.txt"
boolean exists = false
if (props.containsKey('MASTER_STRING')) {
   def masterList = props.MASTER_STRING.split(/ /)
   exists = masterList.findAll { a ->
       subList.any { a.contains(it)}
   }
}
if (exists) {
   println "at least one item exists" // Here I like to print ["foo:321", "bar:888"]
}
```

Comment: `MASTER_STRING` cannot really be a string to achieve this objective. It should ideally be recast as a list/array/slice/etc.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, I converted that to list `masterList`

Comment: So it is unclear to me what the gap is between current and desired functionality, but it sounds like you are asking about https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_collect.htm.

Comment: Thanks Matt, your comment helped me :)

Answer (score 1):

Showing it withoug reading files, instead having 2 lists.

```
masterList= ['aaa:123','bbb:002','ggg:003']
subList = ['aaa:', 'bbb:']
println masterList.findAll {
   a -> subList.any { a.contains(it)}
}
```

prints `[aaa:123, bbb:002]` and this is what I want, I overly complicated this in my question. thanks @Matt for your comment.